# Using grepl for multipe texts

Tags: r, grepl

Lets assume that I have the following variables:

```
a <- c('one','two','three')
b <- c('one|on','two|wo',"three|thre")
c <- c('there is one','there one is ','there is one three two')
```

And I want a new variable with the following results:

```
 d
 [1] "one"   "one"   "three"
```

What I am trying to do is to find if for example the word `one` or `on` is in the text, then assign a new value `one` to a new variable `d`. Also if there are multiple values from `a` the hierarchy should be from the last value.

What I can do is the following:

```
d <- list()
d[grepl(b[1],c)] <- a[1]
d[grepl(b[2],c)] <- a[2]
d[grepl(b[3],c)] <- a[3]
d <- unlist(d)
```

The same can be done in a simple loop. But is there any other way more elegant?

Comment: Have you looked into `stri_replace_all_regex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not all that elegant, but this function does what you want:

```
funny_replace <- function(c, b, a) {

   max_or_null <- function(x) {
      if (length(x) != 0) max(x) else NULL
   }

   multi_grep <- function(b, x) {
      which(sapply(b, grepl, x))
   }

   replace_one <- function(s, b, a) {
      a[max_or_null(multi_grep(b, s))]
   }

   unlist(sapply(c, replace_one, b, a)) 
}
funny_replace(c, b, a)
#      there is one          there one is  there is one three two 
#             "one"                  "one"                "three"
```

It works as follows: `max_or_null` is used to return either the maximum value of a vector or `NULL`, if the vector is empty. This is used later to ensure that elements of `c`, where no pattern from `b` matched, are handled correctly.

`multi_grep` searches multiple patterns in a single string (the usual grep does the opposite: one pattern in multiple strings) and returns the indices of the patterns that were found.

`replace_one` takes a single string and checks, which of the patterns in `b` are found using `multi_grep`. It then uses `max_or_null` to either return the largest of these indices, or NULL if nothing matched. Finally, the element with this index is picked from `a`.

`replace_one` is then applied to each element of `c` to get the desired result.

I think, it's a more functional solution than yours or a for loop, since it avoids the repeated assignment. On the other hand, it seems a bit complicated.

By the way: I have used `a`, `b`, and `c` everywhere to make it easier to match my code to youre example. However, this is not good considered good practice.

Comment: I liked the answer. but Its kinda not so readable. What I didnt like is that it doesnt return the same size as the input size. It returns only the values that matches the input one. So I modify it a little by adding two lines to replace NULL with NA. (I removed the unlist line): Result <- as.character(sapply(c,replace_one,b,a)); Result[Result=='character(0)] <- NA

Comment: Actualy, your solution does not return the same size as the input as well, which is why I made my solution the way I did. A simpler way to have output with the same size as the input would be to replace `NULL` by `NaN` in `max_or_null` (which should then probably be renamed to `max_or_nan`...). This works because `a[NaN]` is `NA`.

Comment: It does return the same size. Maybe i had to mention that the last line is `Result` to output the whole vector.

Comment: I was refering to the code in your question. What you propose in your comment works fine.

Comment: You are right. I did't understand it. Thanks for your comment. btw it seems that when there is an emty character '' it always return the emty character.